# package ntheorem seems not to obey the LaTeX-kernel's old protection mechanism

Tags: auxiliary-files, ntheorem, robust-commands

*This question is related to my answer to the question

[Construct math super/sub-script from reference (`\ref`) with hyperref and cleveref being loaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633926/118714):*

> [...]
> In the example below this is done via defining things in terms of `\protected\def`. (For some obscure reason `\DeclareRobustCommand` does not work out
> when `\@writefile`-entries for the thm-file are written to the
> aux-file.)

---

`\DeclareRobustCommand` belongs to the LaTeX-kernel's old protection mechanism/to the LaTeX-kernel's old expansion-prevention mechanism.

When using `\addcontentsline` for placing a `\@writefile`-entry into the aux-file, robustness of macros defined in terms of `\DeclareRobustCommand` is obeyed.

When loading the ntheorem-package, one can use `\listtheorems{...}` for creating lists of theorems.
Internally a file `\jobname.thm` is created via `\@writefile`-entries that are placed into the .aux-file.

Seems robustness of macros defined in terms of `\DeclareRobustCommand` is not obeyed when `\@writefile{thm}`-entries are placed into the .aux-file due to environments defined in terms of `\newtheorem`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{MyTheorem}{Some theorem}
\renewcommand{\theMyTheorem}{\theMyTheoremformatting{\number\value{MyTheorem}}}%
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\theMyTheoremformatting{\@arabic}
%\protected\def\theMyTheoremformatting{\@arabic}
\newcommand\somethingexpandable{somethingexpandable}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{thm}{undef}{\somethingexpandable}

\addcontentsline{thm}{undef}{\theMyTheoremformatting}

\begin{MyTheorem}[Testing]
\label{Testing}%
Testing things is funnny.
\end{MyTheorem}

\end{document}
```

This is the content of the resulting aux-file:

```latex
\relax 
\@writefile{thm}{\contentsline {undef}{somethingexpandable}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{thm}{\contentsline {undef}{\theMyTheoremformatting  }{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{thm}{\contentsline {MyTheorem}{{Some theorem}{1}{Testing}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{Testing}{{\theMyTheoremformatting  {1}}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

With the first `\@writefile`-entry, due to the first `\addcontentsline`-command, `\somethingexpandable` is expanded as expected.

With the second `\@writefile`-entry, due to the second `\addcontentsline`-command, `\theMyTheoremformatting` is not expanded. This is expected because `\theMyTheoremformatting` is defined in terms of `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

**With the third `\@writefile`-entry, due to the `MyTheorem`-environment, `\theMyTheoremformatting` is expanded. This is not expected because `\theMyTheoremformatting` is defined in terms of `\DeclareRobustCommand`.**

Within the `\newlabel`-entry `\theMyTheoremformatting` is not expanded. This is expected because `\theMyTheoremformatting` is defined in terms of `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

I'd expect the aux-file to look as it looks when defining `\theMyTheoremformatting` in terms of `\protected\def`:

```latex
\relax 
\@writefile{thm}{\contentsline {undef}{somethingexpandable}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{thm}{\contentsline {undef}{\theMyTheoremformatting }{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{thm}{\contentsline {MyTheorem}{{Some theorem}{\theMyTheoremformatting {1}}{Testing}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{Testing}{{\theMyTheoremformatting {1}}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Question:

Am I overlooking an important reason for `\@writefile`-entries produced by theorem-environments not obeying the old protection-mechanism?
Can this be considered a bug/s.th. which the maintainers of ntheorem should be informed about?

---

Excerpt from the .log-file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex-dev 2021.2.27)  15 FEB 2022 18:20
entering extended mode
[...]
LaTeX2e <2021-05-01> pre-release-1 (develop 2021-2-27 branch)
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/11/23 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/11/23 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ntheorem/ntheorem.sty
Style `ntheorem', Version 1.33 <2011/08/15>
Package: ntheorem 2011/08/15 1.33
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The internal macro `\thm@@thmcaption` does `\edef` instead of `\protected@edef`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newtheorem{MyTheorem}{Some theorem}
\renewcommand{\theMyTheorem}{\theMyTheoremformatting{\number\value{MyTheorem}}}%
\makeatletter
% use \protected@edef, not \edef
\xpatchcmd{\thm@@thmcaption}{\edef}{\protected@edef}{}{}

\DeclareRobustCommand\theMyTheoremformatting{\@arabic}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{MyTheorem}[Testing]
\label{Testing}
Testing things is funnny.
\end{MyTheorem}

\end{document}
```

The `.aux` file now has

```
\relax 
\@writefile{thm}{\contentsline {MyTheorem}{{Some theorem}{\theMyTheoremformatting  {1}}{Testing}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{Testing}{{\theMyTheoremformatting  {1}}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Comment: @UlrichDiez The package has not been updated for more than 10 years.